# What is your favorite color of (a) t-shirt?

Tags: nouns

Is it true that this is correct?

> 1 What is your favorite colour of t-shirt?

and this is wrong

> 2 What is your favorite colour of a t-shirt?

If the answer is yes, can you explain the phenomenon in terms of grammar?

Comment: what about *What tee colour is your favourite?*

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ask the question is:

What is your favourite T-shirt color/colour?

Putting *colour* at the end makes it clearer that you are asking about a favourite colour, not a favourite T-shirt. That sentence has the same structure as

What is your favourite dog breed?

What is your favourite skirt length?

What is your favourite pizza topping?

If you put T-shirt at the end, the listener might think you are asking them, out of all the T-shirts they own, which one is in the colour they like best.

Answer (score 0):

Both are wrong.

Omit **a & of**.

Correct: **What is your favourite color t-shirt?**

Idiomatically, any noun that follows **color** (house, car etc) does so without a preposition. This is true for some other words, as in:

**What model car do you prefer?**

The same would be true for **size** although **of** is sometimes possible as well.

**What size (of) t-shirt do you take?**.

There are exceptions that always require **of**:

**What kind/type/sort of machine are you looking for?**

**What blend of whisky would you choose?**

You just have to get to know them.

Comment: "What is your favourite color t-shirt?" doesn't sound right to me... what part does "t-shirt" play in this question?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: It's certainly an idiomatically established usage for Brits. See [*What's your favourite colour car?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22your+favourite+colour+car%22) in Google Books. But switching to US spelling [*your favorite color car*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22your+favorite+color+car%22) seems to actually get ***less*** hits rather than more, so maybe Americans in general aren't so keen on the usage.

Comment: The reason why I consider this "What is your favorite colour of t-shirt?" is because two native speakers confirmed the correctness similar sentences such as "what is you favorite color of car?" and "what is your favorite genre of movie?" As for the idiomatic way of putting it, I wasn't asking about it, though, thank you for sibmitting it. Still I was and am interested only in the two original sentences.

Comment: ...you also see *What's your favourite colour **of** car* (which is fine by me, though I wouldn't normally include that optional preposition myself). There aren't any instances of this construction with an "extraneous" indefinite article *(What's your favourite colour of **a** car?)* in Google Books, but that usage s explored [here on WordReference.com.](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/your-favorite-color-of-horse-of-a-horse-of-horses.3706886/)

Comment: Syntactically, both the preposition AND the aricle are effectively optional. I suspect Americans in particular are more tolerant of the article *(favorite colour of **a** t-shirt)*, but my guess is that even in the US, ***most*** native speakers won't like that version much. Personally, I think if you're going to have an article there, you should change the preposition: *What is your favorite colour **for a** t-shirt?*

Comment: As a Brit, *what's your favourite colour car* is a typical way to phrase it, but it's definitely a "lazy" way of saying *favourite colour **of** car* by dropping a word, and it doesn't always sound natural in every situation either, so I'd be careful about using it. *What's your favourite length skirt* sounds fine, *what's your favourite cut skirt* sounds strange. You need to be aware that the *of* is supposed to be there I think - if it can be interpreted as an adjective directly modifying a noun, your brain starts to think "what's a cut skirt?" But not "what's a length skirt?"

Comment: Don't you think that "What is your favourite color t-shirt?" asks about the T-shirt with a favourite color? But ""What is your favourite t-shirt color ?" asks about a favorite color of T-shirt.